# Phabricator Sprint Extension Issue

Tags: phabricator

I have installed phabricator extension Sprint from this link https://github.com/wikimedia/phabricator-extensions-Sprint for viewing sprint reports in phabricator. After performing the installation,when I open the phabricator site I am getting the following exception

```
PhutilBootloaderException
Include of '/var/www/html/myapp/phabricator/libext/Sprint/src/__phutil_library_init__.php' failed!
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you ran the commands: `./config set load-libraries '{"sprint":"/srv/phab/libext/sprint/src"}'` and `ln -s /srv/phab/libext/sprint/rsrc/webroot-static /srv/phab/phabricator/webroot/rsrc/sprint`? When I skipped those I had similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to run `arc liberate` from inside the Sprint extension's root directory.

See https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/ for complete documentation about adding extensions to phabricator.